# How do I have a Cognos 8 Report use data from another Report as a filter?

Tags: parameters, filter, report, cognos-8

I'm working with a lot of reports that use the same data parameters in filters. Periodically that data changes and I have to go through every report and change the one parameter so that the filter functions properly. Is there a way I can make my reports reference either another report or file for this filter so that I only have to change the source, rather than going through every report and modifying the filter?
I've tried a few things with the report parameters, but I'm not sure how to have the parameters set to anything other than data from a prompt.
If I wasn't clear enough, please tell me and I'll try to make my question clearer?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get your modeler to standardize your filters in Framework Manager, and make them available in your package. Then use the package based filters in your report. When the filter criteria changes, change it in the framework and republish the package. Then all reports inherit this change.